# my css for each page is not being altered when i change it but when i delete the link to it then it effects it

Tags: php, html, css

I have used PHP require function to link my header and footer style.css to all my other pages however the other pages also have their own specific CSS files but when I make a change to them it doesn't have an effect but I know that the style on  the pages is being provided because they are the only pages with that specific style and it only deletes it if I remove the CSS link to them. Any suggestions as to why this is? I want to add CSS to these pages but its not being affected.

```php
<?php
  require_once "../addons/header.php";
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Messages-inbox.css" type="text/css"/>
```

I used require for the header CSS  and then the html link for the pages own unique CSS but I noticed the changes I make to each of the CSS files only happens if I rename the file after each change not sure why its like this

```css
.secondarynavi

    gation-messages a:hover {
      color: #fd886b;
      border: 1px solid #fd886b;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    
    .secondarynavigation-messages a:hover::before {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .secondarynav-messages ::after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .secondarynavigation-messages a::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #fd886b;
        position: relative;
        top: 40px;
        width: 0%;
        transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
    }
    
    .messages-nav-line {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #e6e6e1;
        padding: 1px 0px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 10px;
      }
```

this is the CSS for the page I'm working on and if I delete this CSS from the page it doesn't do anything to the webpage the effect only takes place when I remove the link to this CSS but this is the only page with this specific CSS

Comment: do you have at least a minimal reproductive code? Its easier to understand when we can see what you actually did. However it sounds like that you choose a very complicated solution. Why use multiple CSS files in the first place. You can style the header and footer in one css file as every other content. If you want to use the same header and footer at multiple pages, use PHP Templates `<?php include (path); ?>`

Comment: thats what i did but i used require instead of include

Comment: in that case you should have only one css file, that from the main page. the temples itself cant have a different css file. include/require injects the code from the template into its own page server sided. Means the head of the page not the template will be used (as matter of fact the template shouldnt even have either a head or body)

Comment: your css is being cached , the only thing you need make a version of your css, by using unix timestamp or random number

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="Messages-inbox.css?ver=<?php echo(mt_rand(1,500));?>" />                                                                                                                                                like this? not sure how and i don't get why?

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can prevent your css files from being cached by adding a query string with a random number.

Try somehting like this where you call your css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Messages-inbox.css?ver=<?php echo(mt_rand(1,500));?>" />
```